# Is there another way to emulate Fl studio's Gross beat time manipulation

Tags: daw, effects, fl-studio

I am creating a song full of time manipulation and tape stop effects, but putting gross beat in different channels and routing other channels to is is making my work disorganized and its eating my CPU. I've used glitch, and its the same thing. Is there another way, maybe with automation and fl studio's default plugin to create these time manipulations and tape stop effects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating the Tape stop is making a sound slowdown and bringing the pitch down at the same time. In fl studio, it will be easier to use the pitch envelope or slide to crate this effect. It will save CPU and keep your work organized. [This video explains different ways to to do the tape stop effect.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-S8dS2yBMr4)

Answer (score 2):

There are a multitude of ways to do things like this as it's FL and it's great.

For the time jumps, this is as simple as cutting and pasting bits of audio files where you want them. You could figure out the patterns you're using in Gross Beat and recreate them with the cut audio. Do note that this is very time consuming, but your CPU will thank you.

For the time stops, I would look into the stretching modes in FL's default sampler. We have the new one that removes time and pitch errors, but you could try putting it on resample mode and playing a MIDI note and sliding it downwards. This makes the pitch go down, but it will slow down. You can also try and find one that will keep the pitch the same, but still affect time when pitch-shifted - then this same MIDI will create the tape-stop effect you need.

I have just quickly typed this out so if you need more information or an example then ask and I'll go into more depth.

Have fun.

Comment: ok. I understand doing the tape stop effect with time stretching, but i don't still understand how you can achieve gross beats time manipulation if you're working with midi not audio.

Comment: The time manipulation would be done with the audio. My answer explains how you can cut, paste, and rearrange the audio to create the effect. The MIDI and time-stretching options in the sampler would be used for the tape stop.